# Trying to select all objects that do not have any object.objects2.property = value with doctrine

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an object "order" that has multiple "request" objects. Each request object has a property "status":

```
Order:
- id
- requests

Request:
- id
- status
```

What I now want to do is select all orders that do not have any request with the status = 'value'

I can do the opposite with doctrine (i.e selecting all orders that have at least one request with status = 'value') by the following code:

```
 $queryBuilder->andWhere("order.requests.status = value");
```

If I now replace the = with a !=, then it returns the object if one request fulfills the condition. However, I need the object only if all requests of the object match the condition.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you show the whole Query ?

Comment: solved it by doing a
$queryBuilder->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->notIn('o.id', $select)); where the select was the one from above esetnially.